# What is the difference between creating new Stream and using Write method?

Tags: c#, memorystream

I am working on an mp3 streaming application and stacked at one point. There are two different code part to read the `Stream` and to store it in a `MemoryStream`, but one of them is not working properly.

**First method:**

```
do
{
  bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, bigBuffer, total, bytesRead);
  total += bytesRead;
  pos = ms.Position;
  ms = new MemoryStream(bigBuffer);
  ms.Position = pos;
  frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(ms);
}
while (bytesRead > 0)
```

**Second Method:**

```
do
{
  bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  total += bytesRead;
  pos = ms.Position;
  ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  ms.Position = pos;
  frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(ms);
}
while (bytesRead > 0)
```

In these code, the position of the `MemoryStream` is stored and set again after `MemoryStream` is processed or changed. But the second method is not working as I expected.

The key point is the difference between `new MemoryStream(byte[] array)` and `MemoryStream.Write(array, 0, count)`. Does they work different? I was thinking they are the same. What is the reason of this problem?

Comment: You've obviously read MSDN articles for both constructors, so why you expect them to behave the same way?

Comment: In both situation, we have the same `MemoryStream` contains the same `bigBuffer` data, doesn't we? I think like that because we get the same `MS` by creating new `MemoryStream` passing `bigBuffer` as parameter in the first method and by appending the buffer after the where `Position` stays  in the second method.

Comment: You really should re-read [MemoryStream constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k(v=vs.110).aspx)... If that does not help - check Length property.